# Scraping dataTable gets only header

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to get some salary data from [the Feds Data Center](http://www.fedsdatacenter.com/federal-pay-rates/index.php?n=&l=&a=CONSUMER+FINANCIAL+PROTECTION+BUREAU&o=&y=2016). There are 1537 entries to read. I thought I'd gotten the table xpath with Chrome's `Inspect`. However, my code is only returning the header. I would love to know what I'm doing wrong.

```
library(rvest)
url1 = 'http://www.fedsdatacenter.com/federal-pay-rates/index.php?n=&l=&a=CONSUMER+FINANCIAL+PROTECTION+BUREAU&o=&y=2016'
read_html(url1) %>%  html_nodes(xpath="//*[@id=\"example\"]") %>%
html_table()
```

I get only the (lonely) header:

```
[[1]]
[1] Name       Grade      Pay Plan   Salary     Bonus      Agency     Location  
[8] Occupation FY        
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

My desired result is a data frame or data.table with all the 1537 entries.

Edit: Here's the relevant info from Chrome's inspect, header is in `thead` and data is in `tbody` `tr`
[image: inspect screenshot]

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the fact that this specific page uses AJAX calls to populate the table ***after*** loading the page. I'm researching the solution to this issue.

Comment: I tried downloading the web page and scrapping that.  The body of the table is blank.  The basic methods are not going to work.

Comment: Their data comes from OPM, which posts its data on [data.gov](http://catalog.data.gov/organization/opm-gov) in much more convenient formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site does not expressly forbid scraping data. Their Terms of Use are somewhat generic and taken from the main http://www.fedsmith.com/terms-of-use/ site (so it appears to be boilerplate). They aren't doing anything with the source *free* data that adds any value. I also agree you should just use the source data http://www.opm.gov/data/Index.aspx?tag=FedScope vs rely on this site being around.

But…

It also doesn't require using `RSelenium`.

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

res <- GET("http://www.fedsdatacenter.com/federal-pay-rates/output.php?n=&a=&l=&o=&y=&sEcho=2&iColumns=9&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=100&mDataProp_0=0&mDataProp_1=1&mDataProp_2=2&mDataProp_3=3&mDataProp_4=4&mDataProp_5=5&mDataProp_6=6&mDataProp_7=7&mDataProp_8=8&iSortingCols=1&iSortCol_0=0&sSortDir_0=asc&bSortable_0=true&bSortable_1=true&bSortable_2=true&bSortable_3=true&bSortable_4=true&bSortable_5=true&bSortable_6=true&bSortable_7=true&bSortable_8=true&_=1464831540857")

dat <- fromJSON(content(res, as="text"))
```

It makes an XHR request for the data and it's paged. In the event it's not obvious, you can increment `iDisplayStart` by `100` to page through the results. I made this using my `curlconverter` package. The `dat` variable also has a `iTotalDisplayRecords` component that tells you the total.

The *entirety* of browser Developer Tools are your friend and can usually help avoid the clunkiness & slowness & flakiness of browser instrumentation.

Comment: Guess I'm not sure how to read and interpret terms of use!  It is possible to get all 1537 entries by changing `iDisplayLength=10` to `iDisplayLength=1537`.

Comment: No, they seem to have set a "sane" hard limit of 100 entries max per page. Which is prbly more due to whatever back-end library they used that is DataTables savvy (builtwith.com suggests it's some PHP lib)

Comment: Yea, you can only display 100 on the page at a time.  Unless I'm misunderstanding, though, I can get all 1537 entries from `http://www.fedsdatacenter.com/federal-pay-rates/output.php?n=&a=CONSUMER%20FINANCIAL%20PROTECTION%20BUREAU&l=&o=&y=2016&sEcho=2&iColumns=9&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=1537`

Comment: There are 97,697 records in this example (I just went with the default screen for a more 'teach to fish' effect) and I tried putting that in and it didn't work but other, larger values do seem to work so the OP will need to test what works best (but not too much since I'd ban their IP address if they tried this with a site I setup like this :-)

Answer (score 1):

*Note: Aside from dealing with the Terms of Use of the specific website, I will be showing how to get data from similar websites who are using AJAX techniques.*

Because the website loads the data ***after*** the webpage is loaded into the browser, `rvest` alone is not enough to deal with this kind of problem.

To download data from this website, we need to act as a web browser and control the browser programmatically. **Selenium** and `RSelenium` package can help us do that.

```
#Loading package, downloading(if needed) and starting the Server
library(RSelenium)
RSelenium::checkForServer()    
RSelenium::startServer()

#Starting the browser, so we see what's happening
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost" 
                      , port = 4444
                      , browserName = "firefox"
)

#navigating to the website
remDr$open()
remDr$getStatus()
remDr$navigate(url1)

# Find table
elem <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "example")

# Read its HTML
elemHtml <- elem$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]

# Read HTML into rvest objects
htmlObj <- read_html(elemHtml)
htmlObj %>% html_table()
```

So, after getting the Html from Selenium, we can deal with it through `rvest`.

Comment: BTW, using Selenium you can click the next button and get the rest of the data, as well.

Comment: We do not, in fact, have to use [R]Selenium to get to this data.